# Ошибка “Undefined offset: 1 in…”

Tags: php, html

Вот сам код:

```
        $steamID64 = is_numeric($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 0;
    }
```

Ошибка:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /storage/ssd4/170/5470170/public_html/inc/classes/steamLogin.class.php on line 116

Comment: `$steamID64 = isset($matches[1]) && is_numeric($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 0;`

Comment: Спасибо, ошибки больше нету